# Bind9 DNS resolves full domain to localhost

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ping, localhost

I have set up a Bind9 DNS server on my development VM which is running Debian Wheezy. My addresses resolve from my host machine (Win7) to my dev VM, and I can ping from there. Internally on the VM, I can ping my names (www, share, my_name, etc.) and it resolves to the correct ip (11.11.11.11). But when I ping my full FDQN (www.app.dev), it resolves to localhost. This is not true for my_name.app.dev, only the CNAME entries in my db.app.dev file in my /etc/bind/ folder. So if I ping www, resolves to 11.11.11.11, www.app.dev resolves to 127.0.0.1. Pinging www.app.dev or just www from outside the DNS VM resolves fine. Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

Here are the files I think you want. I added resolv.conf in case there's something wrong there.

/etc/bind/zones/db.app.dev

```
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA app.dev. root.app.dev. (
                 15     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;

app.dev.   IN NS my_name.app.dev.
app.dev.   IN A 11.11.11.11
;@  IN  A   127.0.0.1
;@  IN  AAAA    ::1
my_name     IN A 11.11.11.11
gateway     IN A 11.11.11.2
vmhost      IN A 11.11.11.1
www         IN CNAME app.dev.
stream      IN CNAME app.dev.
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "app.dev" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.app.dev";
};

zone "11.11.11.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.11";
};
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
domain app.dev
search app.dev
nameserver 11.11.11.11
```

Here is the hosts file
/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1                       localhost
11.11.11.11 my_name.app.dev     my_name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
#::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
#ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
#ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

dig provided:
`dig www.app.dev any #=>`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> www.app.dev any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51223
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.app.dev.           IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.app.dev.        604800  IN  CNAME   app.dev.


;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
app.dev.        604800  IN  NS  my_name.app.dev.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
my_name.app.dev.        604800  IN  A   11.11.11.11

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 11.11.11.11#53(11.11.11.11)
;; WHEN: Wed Aug 13 12:48:15 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 78
```

here is the ping: `ping www.app.dev`

```
PING www.app.dev (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.038 ms
^C
--- www.app.dev ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.032/0.035/0.038/0.002 ms
```

Comment: how is bind configured? Master, slave, or simply replication? If it's not just replication; can you post a copy of the zone file (sanitized)?

Comment: @ericx, I'm not sure what the differences are but here are the files

Comment: Can you include `dig` output that shows the problem?

Comment: As @HåkanLindqvist has suggested, a `dig` would be helpful. I have suggestions; but since I can't format in a comment, they appear below.

Comment: @pdom without `ANY` would have been more helpful, that would match the actual query that would be happening (and we would get to see the `A` record as well).

Answer (score 1):

if you have www setup as your machine hostname in your hosts file (/etc/hosts), it will resolve there first from the local machine (hosts is checked before the resolvers you have setup). Check your hosts file...

Comment: I added the hosts file. I guess that explains why the my_name.app.dev ping resolves correctly. Does that mean that the other ip resolutions ARE expected behavior, or is something not configured correctly?

Comment: They are not expected behavior. Your dig gives the correct result but ping picks the loopback IP address incorrectly. Perhaps it has cached the result from earlier when you had an entry in /etc/hosts pointing to the loopback address? Reboot and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

I forget where `isc-bind` defaults its logs to; so consider the following addition to your `named.conf`. This is the logging config I've used for the last 10 years or so. It is probably a bit excessive; but it shouldn't miss anything. I'm running on FreeBSD; so the location of the logs may not be perfect. You will also have to create the `namedb` subdirectory and make it writable by BIND (in my case that is `bind:wheel 755`). After you are sure you have good logging (you may already), `grep` for `error` in `/var/log/namedb/general`.

You are doing this to be sure that `named` is happy with your configuration.

(I actually have all this in a file called `named.logs` and I copy it around and `include` it. Contents haven't changed since the introduction of ver. 9 removed the "statistics" category.)

```
logging {
    channel "default_debug" {
    file "/var/log/named.run";  // Redefine the built-in debug
                    // channel; so named.run is
                    // written to a consistent location
    severity dynamic;       // log at the server's
                    // current debug level
    };
    channel "default" {
    file        "/var/log/default" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    //severity  debug 3;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "general" {
    file        "/var/log/general" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "database" {
    file        "/var/log/database" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "security" {
    file        "/var/log/security" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "resolver" {
    file        "/var/log/resolver" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "xfer" {
    file        "/var/log/xfer" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "notify" {
    file        "/var/log/notify" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "client" {
    file        "/var/log/client" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "unmatched" {
    file        "/var/log/unmatched" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "network" {
    file        "/var/log/network" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "update" {
    file        "/var/log/update" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "queries" {
    file        "/var/log/query.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    //severity  debug;
    //print-category    yes;
    //print-severity    yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "dispatch" {
    file        "/var/log/dispatch" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "dnssec" {
    file        "/var/log/dnssec" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "lame-servers" {
    file        "/var/log/lamoes" versions 3 size 100k;
    severity    debug;
    print-category  yes;
    print-severity  yes;
    print-time  yes;
    };
    channel "statistics" {
    // This is for cricket
    file        "/var/log/stats.log" versions 3 size 1k;
    };

    category "default"      { "default"; };
    category "general"      { "general"; };
    category "database"     { "database"; };
    category "security"     { "security"; };
    category "config"       { "general"; };
    category "resolver"     { "resolver"; };
    category "xfer-in"      { "xfer"; };
    category "xfer-out"     { "xfer"; };
    category "notify"       { "notify"; };
    category "client"       { "client"; };
    category "unmatched"    { "unmatched"; };
    category "network"      { "network"; };
    category "update"       { "update"; };
    category "queries"      { "queries"; };
    category "dispatch"     { "dispatch"; };
    category "dnssec"       { "dnssec"; };
    category "lame-servers" { "lame-servers"; };
//    category "statistics" { "statistics"; };
};
```

If it is clear that `named` is running without errors, you need to do some `dig's` (as requested by @Håkan Lindqvist to see specifically what is being reported. e.g.:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 my_name.app.dev.
dig @11.11.11.11 my_name.app.dev.
```

Windows doesn't have `dig`; so you are limited to the deprecated `nslookup` and will (I believe) have to use the interactive mode. Specify various "servers" and query "my_name.app.dev."

Please let us know what you see.

Comment: Windows doesn't ship with `dig` but there's nothing stopping you from using `dig` on Windows. The Windows builds of BIND include `dig.exe` http://www.isc.org/downloads/

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist true